# Output stream operator Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL) for fundamental/STL types/classes

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, operator-overloading, argument-dependent-lookup

I want to convert an `unsigned char` and a `std::vector<unsigned char>` to a hexadecimal string. Currently I am using the output stream `operator<<` to realize the conversion, but that approach seems to have some drawbacks regarding *Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)*. It **just works** only (without additional actions) if I put the two operators in the `std` namespace (see code below).

Four approaches come to my mind, to realize the conversion:

1. Put operator `operator<<` in the same namespace as the type definition. **Problem:** The compiler doesn't find the declaration, a `using` statement has to be used.
2. Put operator `operator<<` in the global namespace. **Problem:** The compiler doesn't find the declaration, I don't know how-to fix that.
3. Put operator `operator<<` in the `std` namespace. **Problem:** Overrides the default behavior and feels wrong.
4. Use some kind of wrapper/proxy in the same namespace as the type definition. **Problem:** I can't make it work with `std::vector`.

The above approaches are realized in the following source code. Approaches 1. and 2. can be tested by moving the two `operator<<` free functions in the `std` namespace to another namespace. The macro `BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL` is used, because it utilizes `operator<<`.

```
// Production code

// STL includes
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

// Boost includes
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/io/ios_state.hpp>
namespace fw {

using Byte = unsigned char;
using ByteVector = std::vector<Byte>;

// 4. Approach

class ByteWrapper final {
 public:
  ByteWrapper(Byte const kByte) : kByte_{kByte} {
    // NOOP
  }

  operator Byte() const {
    return kByte_;
  }

 private:
  Byte const kByte_;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ByteWrapper const& kByte) {
  static_assert(!(CHAR_BIT & 3), "CHAR_BIT has to be a multiple of 4");
  boost::io::ios_all_saver guard{os};

  return os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase
            << std::setw(CHAR_BIT >> 2) << +kByte;
}

inline ByteWrapper to_hex(Byte const kByte) {
  return {kByte};
}

class ByteVectorWrapper final
    : private boost::equality_comparable<ByteVectorWrapper> {
 public:
  ByteVectorWrapper(ByteVector const& kBytes) : kBytes_{kBytes} {
    // NOOP
  }

  // TODO(wolters): This is ugly, why can't a conversion operator be used?
  ByteVector operator() () const {
    return kBytes_;
  }

  bool operator==(ByteVectorWrapper const& kOther) const {
    return kOther.kBytes_ == kBytes_;
  }

 private:
  ByteVector const kBytes_;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
                                ByteVectorWrapper const& kVector) {
  for (auto i = 0; i < (kVector().size() - 1); ++i) {
    os << to_hex(kVector()[i]) << ' ';
  }

  return os << to_hex(kVector()[kVector().size() - 1]);
}

inline ByteVectorWrapper to_hex(ByteVector const& kByteVector) {
  return {kByteVector};
}

}  // namespace fw

// 3. Approach I don't think this a correct approach, since the default
// behavior of the fundamental data type `unsigned char` and the STL template
// class `std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>` is overwritten!

namespace std {

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, fw::Byte const& kByte) {
  static_assert(!(CHAR_BIT & 3), "CHAR_BIT has to be a multiple of 4");
  boost::io::ios_all_saver guard{os};

  return os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase
            << std::setw(CHAR_BIT >> 2) << +kByte;
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
                                fw::ByteVector const& kBytes) {
  for (auto i = 0; i < (kBytes.size() - 1); ++i) {
    // Calls `operator<<(std::ostream&, fw::Byte const&)`.
    os << kBytes[i] << ' ';
  }

  return os << kBytes[kBytes.size() - 1];
}

}  // namespace std

// Test code

#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

namespace {

// If the two operators would have been placed in the `fw` namespace, one of the
// following lines would be required:
//using namespace fw;
//using fw::operator<<;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(OutputStreamOperator_Byte) {
  fw::Byte const kByte{0xA};
  std::cout << kByte << '\n';
  std::cout << fw::to_hex(kByte) << '\n';
  BOOST_REQUIRE(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(OutputStreamOperator_ByteVector) {
  fw::ByteVector const kByteVector{0xA, 0x0, 0xF, 0x9};
  std::cout << kByteVector << '\n';
  std::cout << fw::to_hex(kByteVector) << '\n';
  BOOST_REQUIRE(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(OutputStreamOperator_Byte_Equal) {
  fw::ByteVector const kFirstByte{0xA};
  fw::ByteVector const kSecondByte{kFirstByte};

  BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(kFirstByte, kSecondByte);
  BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(fw::to_hex(kFirstByte), fw::to_hex(kSecondByte));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(OutputStreamOperator_ByteVector_Equal) {
  fw::ByteVector const kFirstByteVector{0xA, 0x0, 0xF, 0x9};
  fw::ByteVector const kSecondByteVector{kFirstByteVector};

  // TODO(wolters): Raises a GCC compiler error if using approach 1. or 2.
  // error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'const std::vector<unsigned char>')
  // ostr << t; // by default print the value
  //      ^

  BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(kFirstByteVector, kSecondByteVector);
  BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(fw::to_hex(kFirstByteVector), fw::to_hex(kSecondByteVector));
}

}  // namespace
```

What do you think? What is a good approach, to realize what I want? Do not rely on the output stream operators at all and use explicit free functions? What about the namespacing? If using operators, in which namespace should I put them and why?

I am using C++11 with GCC 4.7.1 and Boost 1.49.

Comment: "**[namespace.std]/1** The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified." Your approach #3 exhibits UB for this reason.

Comment: Thanks @Igor Tandetnik. Just for completion, section 17.6.4.2.1 of the *International Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2014(E) – Programming Language C++* is quoted here.

Comment: I don't understand the question but generally if possible, it is a good idea to have `friend ostream& operatotr<<(ostream& os, Class const& c>` (which can be defined inside the class).